# Can a Filipino with a green card exit a Japanese airport during a layover without needing a visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, japan, layovers, filipino-citizens

I am a citizen of the Philippines currently living in USA with a green card. I have a ticket to the Philippines with a layover of over 15 hours in Japan.

With my status can I go outside the airport and do some touring or something like that, or am I stuck inside?

Because I know Korea has a layover that offers free touring.

Comment: What times are you arriving and departing?

Answer (score 5):

Your Green card is meaningless for the purpose of transiting Japan

However, **if and only if** there are no connecting flights to your destination on the same calendar day, you can enter Japan visa-free, by presenting your passport and connecting boarding pass, and stay for up to 72 hours.

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ph&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=jp&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines and based on live info from the Japanese government:

> Holders of onward tickets transiting to a third country can
>     obtain a Shore Pass on arrival for a max. stay of 72 hours
>     only if there are no connecting flights on the same calendar
>     day

In fact, if you're connecting at any airport other than Tokyo-Haneda or Osaka-Kansai, **and** your connection is overnight, you'll **have** to enter Japan, as the other airports close at night.

If you have an overnight transfer at any airport other than Tokyo-Haneda or Osaka-Kansai, ignorant check-in staff may try to deny you boarding without a visa. In this case, ask them to check Timatic and tell them you're entering under the Shore pass arrangement.

NOTE: other answers have suggested the issurance of Shore Passes is restricted to emergencies. It is **not**. It would have been correct in 2014, which was reflected by the Timatic info at the time.

On [Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g298161-i2418-k7314795-Visiting_Japan_during_Transit_at_Narita_Shore_Pass-Narita_Chiba_Prefecture_Kanto.html), one user cites Timatic **from 2014**:

> Only in exceptional circumstances (e.g., delays, missed connections or re-routing), visitors continuing their journey to a third country can obtain a Shore Pass/Transit Pass on arrival for a max. stay of 72 hours

Since it isn't expressed like that anymore, the Immigration Bureau in Japan has obviously informed IATA of having become more liberal in granting shore passes.

For what it's worth, I called the Immigration Bureau's head office yesterday, and was told that Timatic was up-to-date (I explained what it said, and asked if there were any further restrictions, to which they said no)

So again, you do **not** need a visa, and again, if an ignorant check-in clerk tries to deny you boarding, ask them to check Timatic, because, although immigration authorities aren't bound by it, check-in staff for IATA-connected airlines (the vast majority) **definitely** is

Comment: Timatic is irrelevant here, Maybe airlines follow it, but Japanese immigration definitely doesn't.

Comment: @fkraiem In what way do the rules of Japanese immigration differ? You do know Timatic's based on info from Japanese immigration authorities?

Comment: "You do know Timatic's based on info from Japanese immigration authorities?" No, I don't know that. Show me something from the immigration bureau that says this and I will.

Comment: @fkraiem I speak to the Timatic team, and they do **not** make up their rules out of thin air; rather, they have a dedicated government source in every country that notifies them of any changes.

Comment: @Crazydre Is there any way to find the "source" of TimTics immigration information on Japan? It doesn't actually state it in either the link you provided, the Japanese customs website or on the TimTic website that I could find. Also, as fkraiem says, there are times when Japanese Immigration are a law unto themselves and travellers with valid visas or those meeting valid entry requirements are denied (as entry is decided by an official, not a computer system).

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Officers not doing their job propely is always an existent risk, in any country, however what Timatic is informed of is **actual practice at the border**, even if different from formal law.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder "Also, "Is there any way to find the "source" of TimTics immigration information on Japan?" Not online, they're not getting it from the Internet, but through continuous correspondance with the relevant authorities, in the case of Japan the Immigration Bureau. Beats me why the Immigration Bureau doesn't have information about the shore pass online

Comment: @Crazydre But the officers are doing their job properly. Your absolute faith in the general entry requirements and allocations displayed on Timatic does not trump the Immigration Laws of countries involved. Timatic displays general entry information, and any special occasions that differ from normal practices (riots, strikes, Presidential Decrees. As Japanese Immigration states (and is usually the case almost everywhere else in the world)...

Comment: ..."Applicants should be aware that a visa does not guarantee entry into Japan. The Ministry of Justice (the Immigration Office) has the authority to deny admission. A visa is used solely to make application for Landing Permission, which defines the period for which a foreign national is authorized to remain in Japan, and the Status of Residence, which determines the activities a foreign national is authorized to engage in in Japan. Landing Permissions are determined by the immigration official at the port of entry, not the consular official."

Comment: @Crazydre The thing is, most if not all the information Timatic offers for Japan, ***IS*** available online through the Ministry of Justice Website, which also lists the various laws and associated Diet Decrees. Alas, even a short disclaimer stating "Information Correct as of 2017 02 20 - Ministry of Justice, Japan" or something to that effect would fulfil the "source" part of my question.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder You are right, of course, but I don't see how this strengthens the common argument that the Shore Pass "isn't generally an actual option in practice" and that you need to get a transit visa instead, which is basically the issue at hand.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder "The thing is, most if not all the information Timatic offers for Japan, IS available online through the Ministry of Justice Website" Isn't it the text that states shore passes are applied for by the carrier? Again, this used to be the case, but it's outdated, and it's no surprise, since South Korea is also lazy about updating their Immigration-related websites

Comment: @Crazydre After some digging round a few of the J-Gov sites (MLIT,MOJ etc.) I have found that the Shore Pass is covered in Article 14 of Immigration Law and apart from restricting validity to 72 hours for those transiting **by air**, it also restricts movement to the immediate town/city that hosts each International Airport (except in the case of Narita where travel to Tokyo appears to also be in scope). Almost 90% of cases where this pass is given are to those crew travelling on seafaring vessels (specifically cargo ships) and the validity is usually 15 days (as a Tourist Shore Pass)...

Comment: The application in these circumstances still has to be applied for by the captain of the vessel. However, for air flight, as of mid 2015, and especially in and around Narita City, Shore Passes are being granted in an increasing number to bring in "Short term shopping shore leave" arrangements as part of a promotion by Narita City. It does appear as though Shore Passes are now being granted with more regularity, however, there is still no guarantee, nor right to be granted one (as this is purely at the discretion of Japanese Immigration).

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder "there is still no guarantee, nor right to be granted one (as this is purely at the discretion of Japanese Immigration)." Absolutely, same with being granted admission on a visa. "it also restricts movement to the immediate town/city that hosts each International Airport (except in the case of Narita where travel to Tokyo appears to also be in scope)". Sorry, but is that supposed to be news? If you read Timatic that's what it says exactly as well (it talks about the airport/seaport of arrival and departure having to be in the same "group")

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Kudos for the research btw, would it be possible to link the sources you checked?

Comment: @Crazydre Apologies, I did not see the grouping explanation in Timatic (I have seen it now). Under the same section it claims that "NOTE 6636: The Shore Pass is not available for passengers holding only a US Permanent Resident/Resident Alien Card (Form I-551) or US "Permit to Re-Enter" (Form I-327)." Doesn't that mean that OP with a green card (ie. Form I-551) is not permitted to obtain a Shore Leave Pass? Or does the Philippine Passport cancel the "only" part of that note?

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder You must have a passport to enter Japan (which is also listed among the conditions) - a green card is not accepted. That's what it means. So OP need only present his passport and connecting ticket

Answer (score 0):

USA Green Card is irrelevant in Japan.

Philippines is not in the list of visa waiver so to leave any airport you have to get a visa.

If you have to leave airport for transfer or overnight in case of Narita airport which is not working during night you **must** apply for **Transit Visa**. Transit Visa are not issued for fun to spend some time in Japan, you have to provide evidence that transfer requires airport leaving or staying overnight.

Existing **Shore Passes** are issued **only in case of emergency**. For example you got late for your transfer which did not require Transit visa and had to buy ticket which requires transfer to another airport. If you had to transfer stay overnight with airport leaving and that was expected from the beginning you will not get Shore Pass, yet some exceptions are known. In few cases people had to pay for staying in guarded hotel room for whole time needed to transfer next day or two, paying not only for room but for guard.

**Shore Pass** is not an agreement, officers do not know or care about any **Timatic** or any other website. In many situations they can reject you just because they don't like you **even if you have a visa** and there is no way to object.

- Pamphlet from [Kyushu university.](http://cafs.kyushu-u.ac.jp/borders/kanri/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/BorderBites-vol01.pdf)
- [ANA information.](https://www.ana.co.jp/wws/ind/e/local/ana_info/notice120116/index.html)

In any case neither Transit Visa nor Shore Pass are issued without real purpose.

Comment: Although I agree with most of your points, do you have any evidence (links etc.) to back up your claims.

Comment: "Existing Shore Pass are issued only in case of emergency" **Wrong!** I know this was the case around 2014 (and it was stated in Timatic as such) but it's become more liberal since. "In many situations they can reject you just because they don't like you even if you have a visa and there is no way to object" Of course, but this doesn't justify the argument that a transit visa is needed. Again, it's not restricted to emergencies - another user on this site can testify to that: bonacci, who entered on a it in a non-emergency, and I recently called the Japanese Immigration bureau and asked